# Ubuntu 20.04 rejects user password when connecting to windows printer via samba?

Tags: networking, server, printing, password, samba

I've installed python3-smbc and smbclient, and also samba-common as per usual. It seems that the browser for displaying network shares under "Add Windows Printer via Samba" will not work as in the past, and cannot browse at all, and you must type the specific address, and even then, when it finally connects it rejects the user/password displaying the message "not authorized".

All the past Ubuntu stable distros had no trouble networking through Samba to windows servers/printers over many years. Something has changed.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

It's impossible to install the windows printer because "windows printer via samba" will not accept the user/password, and returns a "not authorized" window instead.

Here's why.

Since version 4, both Samba Server & Samba Clients do not allow an older level of protocols negotiation. You will have to enable them in either the /etc/samba/smb.conf and if needed, the smb.conf file.

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf file (need root permissions)

in the [global] section, adding the following line:

client min protocol = NT1

Save the file and exit the editor.

You must restart the Samba Service for this change to take effect. In a terminal, enter this command:

sudo service smbd restart

You should be able to access your samba shares successfully. If you still cannot connect to your samba share, you can lower even more the protocol security in smb.conf (not recommended, may need to be created):

sudo nano smb.conf

and adding the line:

client min protocol = CORE

Original link here: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-cant-acces-nas-anymore-after-upgrading-to-20-04/